# Laravel query builder, filtering with include and exclude

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-query-builder

I'm having an issue with some specific include/exclude logic in my query.

table baskets has many specific_fruits. Specific_fruits has regex, and has a field for either include or exclude.

specific_fruit table columns:
'LOGIC', 'REGEX'

Entries:
'include', 'apple'
'exclude', 'pear'

First I'm including all strings with the word 'apple'. This works correctly. However, after that, I want to exclude all fruit strings that also have the word 'pear.'

For example:
'apple banana' should be included
'apple pear' should not.

The includes work correctly. The regex works correctly. When the query gets to exclude.. it's still returning baskets that have ALREADY been included.

Baskets that have already been 'included' in the first WHERE function, need to somehow be excluded.

```
DB::table('examples')
   ->join('baskets', 'examples.basket_id', 'baskets.id')
   ->leftJoin('specific_fruit', 'specific_fruit.baskets.id', 'baskets.id')
   ->where(function($query) use ($request) {
       $query->where('specific_fruit.logic', 'include') // we're including these
           ->whereRaw('? ~ specific_fruit.regex', ['apple pear']) // we want to include all "apple" 
           ->orWhere('specific_fruit.logic', 'exclude') // grab all excluded fruit for now, we'll purge the ones next step
   })
   ->where(function($query) use ($user_data, $request) {
       $query->where('specific_fruit.logic', 'include') // retain the included fruit from the previous query
           ->orWhere('specific_fruit.logic', 'exclude') // when we exclude these, it's not removing the ones that are already "included"
           ->whereRaw('? !~ specific_fruit.regex',['apple pear']) // if regex DOES NOT match (!~), exclude that basket
   })
```

Comment: You should use `distinct` and `groupBy` to get unique rows.